# How to change verbosity without restarting geth? (admin.verbosity undefined)

Tags: go-ethereum

Documentation of console API [advertises admin.verbosity](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#adminverbosity), but my node says it's undefined in Geth/v1.4.4-stable-8ea3c88e/linux/go1.6.2. So, how to change verbosity without restaring the node with a different `--verbosity` arg?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation is out of date.

The `verbosity` option is under the `debug` API.

What you want is `debug.verbosity(x)`, where `x` is the logging level.

If you're interested in the code, it's defined in [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/290e851f57f5d27a1d5f0f7ad784c836e017c337/internal/web3ext/web3ext.go) file.